# Hyperlinks within org-babel source code blocks?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'd like to have some hyperlinks on the comments of an org-babel source code block. My goal is to export a file as html and be able to track some references, as in the following minimal example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC lisp
(princ "Hello World!") ;; [[stackoverflow.com/blabla1234][Got this from SO.]]
#+END_SRC
```

"Problem" is that links don't get embedded inside of source code blocks (which actually makes a lot of sense).

Is there a way of overriding this behaviour, or an alternative syntax to insert hyperlinks within src blocks?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not possible now (as of org-mode 8.3.4).  The HTML export engine currently doesn't appear to have a mechanism for escaping protected characters.  You should submit implement it or submit a feature request! ([details](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html))

Some workarounds:

**Imitate the output with raw HTML**

You can output raw HTML that would otherwise look like the source block and it will render with the link intact:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<pre class="src src-sh">
(princ "Hello World!") ;; <a href="stackoverflow.com/blabla1234">Got this from SO.</a>
</pre>
#+END_HTML
```

**Prevent Substitution**
If your code is free of greater than and less than symbols you may be able to prevent them from being substituted with

```
(setq org-html-protect-char-alist '(("&" . "&amp;"))
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
(setq htmlize-basic-character-table
  ;; Map characters in the 0-127 range to either one-character strings
  ;; or to numeric entities.
  (let ((table (make-vector 128 ?\0)))
    ;; Map characters in the 32-126 range to themselves, others to
    ;; &#CODE entities;
    (dotimes (i 128)
      (setf (aref table i) (if (and (>= i 32) (<= i 126))
                   (char-to-string i)
                 (format "&#%d;" i))))
    ;; Set exceptions manually.
    (setf
     ;; Don't escape newline, carriage return, and TAB.
     (aref table ?\n) "\n"
     (aref table ?\r) "\r"
     (aref table ?\t) "\t"
     ;; Escape &, <, and >.
     (aref table ?&) "&amp;"
     ;;(aref table ?<) "&lt;"
     ;;(aref table ?>) "&gt;"
     ;; Not escaping '"' buys us a measurable speedup.  It's only
     ;; necessary to quote it for strings used in attribute values,
     ;; which htmlize doesn't typically do.
     ;(aref table ?\") "&quot;"
     )
    table))
```

Note that both are hacks which simply don't escape the HTML tag delimiters themselves.  If syntax highlighting applies to any characters it will break the resulting HTML link by inserting `<span>`'s.